# Internet Explorer redirect issue

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect, internet-explorer-9

I have a URL shortening service that I built, and am having an issue with Internet Explorer.  I have a link that goes to an mms server (mms://example.com/somelongurl/somevideo.wmv), and it's being redirected from my app (http://short.url/video).

When I click on the link, the video opens and begins to play in Windows Media Player, as expected.  This behavior is the desired effect (one that I can reproduce reliably in Firefox and Chrome).  However, in cases where the the user types in the URL by hand (which will commonly be the case with our URL shortening application), or pastes it into the browser window, it gets a "Webpage cannot be displayed" error.  This only happens on IE; Chrome and Firefox behave as expected.

Additionally, a simple redirect to another web page (for example, http://google.com) works just fine, pasted or clicked or typed.

I suspect it has to do with a security setting, or possibly mime-types, or maybe a combination of both.  The redirect works by setting the header "Location".

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit** I have been examining the headers, and it's sending a 302 status code (which is what I want, so that the script can log the hit.  301 will cache, and the hits won't get logged when the user returns).

IE Developer Tools shows res://ieframe.dll/unknownprotocol.htm in the initiator tab, for Frame URL.

Comment: Any more status updates?  I am experiencing a similar issue with a chatbot URL that redirects away from IE (closes that window) and launches in Chrome -- I suspect a redirect that I cannot catch.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the "Network" tab in the IE Developer Toolbar, or a tool like [FIddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), to examine the HTTP calls